# How to give this custom Seekbar with image?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I would like to make a seek bar something like this :

[image: timer]

I have tried few libraries like this :

https://github.com/tankery/CircularSeekBar and https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar

but I am unable to achieve what I want.

I have the image of this seekbar, can we achieve anything from drawarc or any other idea?

EDIT(28/09/2017) :  :

tried this code, but not able to get desiered result :

```
public class CustomView extends View{

Bitmap gold,grey;
Paint paint;
Context context;
int progress=0;
private Paint mPaint,mPaint2;
private RectF mOval,mOval2;


public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context);
}


public void init(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint();
    gold = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.timer_golden_full);

    grey = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.timer_greyline);

    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mOval = new RectF();
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, gold.getWidth(), gold.getHeight());
    RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 250);
    m.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    Shader shader = new BitmapShader(gold, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    shader.setLocalMatrix(m);
    mPaint.setShader(shader);
    m.mapRect(mOval, src);

    mPaint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mOval2 = new RectF();
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
    RectF src2 = new RectF(0, 0, gold.getWidth(), gold.getHeight());
    RectF dst2 = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 250);
    m2.setRectToRect(src2, dst2, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    Shader shader2 = new BitmapShader(grey, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    shader2.setLocalMatrix(m2);
    mPaint2.setShader(shader2);
    m2.mapRect(mOval2, src2);
}



public void update()
{

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawArc(mOval2, 0, 360, true, mPaint2);
    canvas.drawArc(mOval, 0, 360, true, mPaint);


}
```

}

Comment: yes write a custom view and use `Canvas#drawArc` inside `onDraw` method

Comment: but how will i get the gradient with drawarc @pskink

Comment: it is not a gradient, it is an image, right? then use `BitmapShader`

Comment: yes, how do i do that? draw arc with image?

Comment: see `android.graphics.Paint` documentation on how to setup that bitmap shader

Comment: how do i use bitmapshader

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I am asking for android and the library is for Objective-C

Comment: have you read `android.graphics.Paint` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: i could not find any reference to bitmapshader in android.graphics.Paint. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: @ParthAnjaria https://github.com/sushantbelsare/SeekArc

Comment: because `BitmapShader` is some concrete form of "abstract" `Shader` class

Comment: @pskink now i understood the use of bitmapshader with this link. : https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-how-to-use-bitmapshader.html. But now i am trying to call method getPaint() on progressbar but it is not valid

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the link you provided is only allowing color, but i have an image/gradient to use

Comment: @pskink i have added the code i have tried